# How To Deploy A Modular (Multi-app) System To CloundFoundry

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I'd like to deploy a modular grails app to cloudfoundry. There's a user facing app that should get installed at ROOT as normal, but then there's a separate administration system that should get deployed to the same instance(s) at /admin.

But it looks like you can only deploy 1 app per instance to ROOT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

My understanding is that there's no concept of deploying multiple applications to the same application server instance. In most cases this is OK though. With our BI application we would normally deploy it to the same tomcat instance as another application is running on. But instead we deploy it separately. It can access the same databases, and nothing is preventing Single Sign On between the applications or other integration features from being added.

**EDIT**: application1 presumably is working well and using some database. If you want application2 to access the same data you can just bind it:

```
vmc bind-service my-database-service application2
```

Alternatively, of course, you could merge your two applications together. That will probably give the desired result... but it's probably a big effort.

Comment: How do you ensure both apps hit the save db?

Comment: I edited the answer to show example of binding to the existing database.