# how to use one table in two applications in GORM

Tags: rest, grails, grails-orm

i have created two applications in grails under single database now i want to use single table in both applications 
eg. from one application admin will create the user login credentials
and from other application user should login using the same table. How can i solve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

Domain class must be shared in both applications to achieve that and be able to use GORM. You can create plugin with common domain classes and use it in both applications. We have it working in both Grails 2.x and 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same database configuration for both applications. 
And if you want to run both at the same time, just [run them in different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955899/how-to-change-grails-localhost-port) 
For more information see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844472/grails-one-database-and-more-than-one-application)